# Laravel - both input values can't be no how to validate?

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I'm using Laravel for a project and want to know how to validate a particular scenario I'm facing. I would like to do this with the native features of Laravel if this is possible?

I have a form which has two questions (as dropdowns), for which both the answer can either be yes or no, however it should throw a validation error if both of the dropdowns equal to no, but they can both be yes.

I've check the laravel documentation, but was unsure what rule to apply here, if there is one at all that can be used? Would I need to write my own rule in this case?

Comment: You could just get the value using the `$_POST` array and use `if` statements to validate them... It would nice to see what you have already tried.

Comment: Thanks for your reply David, I was really hoping there might be a native method? In any case, if I did that how would I then throw back the validation error messages in addition to any others that might occur with my other fields in the form - just to be clear the form also consists of fields outside of the two in my question that may cause a validation error

Answer (score 0):

very simple:

let's say both the fields names are *foo* and *bar* respectively.

then:

```
 // Validate for those fields like $rules = ['foo'=>'required', 'bar'=>'required'] etc

 // if validation passes, add this (i.e. inside if($validator->passes()))

 if($_POST['foo'] == 'no' && $_POST['bar'] == 'no')
 {
     $messages = new Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
     $messages->add('customError', 'both fields can not be no');
     return Redirect::route('route.name')->withErrors($validator);
 }
```

the error messge will appear while retrieving.

if you get confuse, just dump the `$error` var and check how to retrieve it. even if validation passes but it gets failed in the above code, it won't be any difference than what would have happened if indeed validation failed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there a benefit to using $_POST over Input::get? Or is it the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously don't know what your form fields are called, but this should work.

This is using the sometimes() method to add a conditional query, where the field value should not be no if the corresponding field equals no.

```
    $data = array(
        'field1' => 'no',
        'field2' => 'no'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make($data, array());
    $validator->sometimes('field1', 'not_in:no', function($input) {
        return $input->field2 == 'no';
    });
    $validator->sometimes('field2', 'not_in:no', function($input) {
        return $input->field1 == 'no';
    });

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        // will fail in this instance
        // changing one of the values in the $data array to yes (or anything else, obvs) will result in a pass
    }
```

Just to note, this will only work in Laravel 4.2+